# Convert defined function into lambda function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

I have been trying to convert the following function into lambda function:

```
def cars(manf, model_name, **car_info):
    """Build a dictionary storing information about a car"""
    car_info['manufacturer'] = manf
    car_info['model'] = model_name
    return car_info
```

Here are my attempts:

```
cars=(lambda manf, model_name,**car_info: car_info['manufacturer']=manf car_info['model']=model_name))
```

Here I get this error:

```
cars=(lambda manf, model_name,**car_info: car_info['manufacturer']=manf car_info['model']=model_name)
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
cars=(lambda manf, model_name,**car_info: car_info.where(car_info['manufacturer']=manf, car_info['model']=model_name))
```

Here I get this error:

```
cars=(lambda manf, model_name,**car_info: car_info.where(car_info['manufacturer']=manf, info['model']=model_name))
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there a way to convert this kind of function into lambda?

Comment: "I have been trying to convert the following function into lambda function" why?

Comment: `cars = lambda manf, model_name, **car_info: dict(manufacturer=manf, model=model_name, **car_info)`?

Comment: Python lambdas are restricted to a SINGLE expression. You have two expressions in your lambda. Maybe create two separate lambdas? Not sure if that would solve your problem as you didn't give much info about the rest of your code. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions